# How to bind InkCanvas height and width to an image

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-cx

I have an Image control in a Grid that is displayed when the user clicks on an image in a list. I want to add an InkCanvas control directly on top of the Image control so the user can draw on it.

However, it seems like the height and width of the InkCanvas is not being bound correctly to the image and I am able to draw outside the image. What else do I need to do?

My XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="result_img" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" x:Load="False" Height="{x:Bind result_img.ActualHeight}" Width="{x:Bind result_img.ActualWidth}"/>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind (C++/CX):

```
void MyGui::test::ListView_ItemClick(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemClickEventArgs^ e)
{
    this->FindName("inkCanvas");
    inkCanvas->InkPresenter->InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes::Mouse;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use element-to-element binding,you should use the **ElementName** property.The ElementName is the name of the control you want to bind and the Path is the property of the control you want to bind.

```
<Image x:Name="result_img"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="400" />
<InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" x:Load="False" Height="{Binding ElementName=result_img, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=result_img, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
```